# PHP "variable wrapper" as an array for SQL queries over multiple databases

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I have 50 databases with the same design and structure. For benchmarking data analysis and evaluation of the several thousand of variables contained therein I need to build SQL queries. I have a SuperAdmin account who has the permission to view all these databases through an SSH access.

Now, I can write SQL queries combining data from one database after another using UNION ALL like this (simplified):

```
SELECT * FROM db1.table WHERE blah
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM db2.table WHERE blah
UNION ALL
[...]
SELECT * FROM db50.table WHERE blah
```

These queries are within a PHP environment and work like a charm - I get all data analyses and evaluations I want.

But:

A single SQL query in my case, however, has about 1.000 lines of query statement and conditional code. Querying 50 databases this sequential way means that my query becomes quite large and I have to do a lot of error-prone copying the SQL query statement adjusting "db1" to "db50" every single time plus within a lot of JOINs additionally, so it becomes a pain in the youknowhere and becomes time-consuming.

My question:

Isn't there a way in which I can tell PHP to put all the "dbx" into an array and reiterate then only the one basic SQL query by exchanging the "dbx" from 1 to 50 using a foreach or while or similar statement?

Such as:

```
<?php
    function getResultValuesFromDatabase() {
        global $DATABASE;

        $db1 = "database1";
        $db2 = "database2";
        [...]
        $db50 = "database50";
        $no_of_databases = array($db1, $db2, [...], $db50);
        foreach ($no_of_databases as $value) {
            $sql_query = "SELECT * FROM $value.table WHERE blah";
        }
        $rQuery = mysql_query($qQuery, $oDatabase);
        $result = array("count" => mysql_num_rows($rQuery ), "result" => $rQuery);
        return $result;
    }
```

I receive an error which affects the reiteration process. Can anybody please tell me where my logical error is?

Comment: whats the error ?

Comment: _Side note:_ Don't use the old and deprecated `mysql_*`-api. It was deprecated back in PHP 5.5 and have been totally removed in PHP 7.

Comment: @Vidal: I must give it to later, just embarked my plane ...

Comment: @MagnusEriksson: I know, rewriting the code for mysqli or PDO is already in the pipeline.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need an array of the names. Since they are all similar a simple `for` loop should work for you. You also need to do the query in the loop and accumulate the results before you return them.

```
for ($db = 1;$db <= 50;$db++) {
     $sql_query = 'SELECT * FROM database' . str_pad($db,2,'0',STR_PAD_LEFT) . '.table WHERE blah';
     $rQuery = mysql_query($qQuery, $oDatabase);
     $result[] = array("count" => mysql_num_rows($rQuery ), "result" => $rQuery);
}
return $result;
```

Comment: Thank you very much, Dave, this solved my problem completely.

Comment: Hello, Dave, I forgot one essential aspect: My databases < 10 have a preceding "0" (so it's database01, database02 ... database10); how can I take care of that?

Comment: `str_pad` is your friend. I modified my answer to include it for you.

Comment: It has not been yet but will be from now on ... ;-); thank you very much, Dave!

Comment: @Dave can you please reopen https://stackoverflow.com/q/59468931/1248953 it?

Answer (score 1):

Of course, you can do it, but you must change the database before doing any request.

Also, please note that `mysql_*` functions are deprecated and you must consider changing them to `mysqli` or `PDO`.

Here is how you could do it:

```
function getResultValuesFromDatabase()
{
    $result = [];

    $con = mysqli_connect("localhost","my_user","my_password");

    for ($i = 1; $i <= 50; $i++) {
         $databaseName = 'database' . str_pad($i, 2, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT);

         mysqli_select_db($con, $databaseName);

         // Probably the database doesn't exist
         if (mysqli_errno($con) !== 0) {
             continue;
         }

         $queryResult = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM table WHERE blah");

         $result[$databaseName] = [
             'count'  => mysqli_num_rows($queryResult),
             'result' => mysqli_fetch_all($queryResult, MYSQLI_ASSOC)
         ];

         mysqli_free_result($queryResult);
    }

    mysqli_close($con);

    return $result;
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much, Matei, changing the entire layout to mysqli or PDO is in the pipeline, very nice of you that you give me here already the proper template for it.

Comment: Hello, Matei, I forgot one essential aspect: My databases < 10 have a preceding "0" (so it's database01, database02 ... database10); how can I take care of that?

Comment: @mtjmohr just edited the answer. The update is pretty the same as Dave already did.

Comment: Thank you very much, too, Matei. I really appreciate your answer.